# Flot: Zoom to Far Right by Default (X-axis disappear when larger data point used)

Tags: flot

This an extension to the question [Flot: Zoom to Far Right by Default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17128827/flot-zoom-to-far-right-by-default) .
Whilst the accepted answers works great for smaller population, But if we have more than 1000 points, the x-axis would be lost, and nothing except the y-axis are displayed, (works again if we set  **left: 0** ), but then it will be zoom to far left.

```
i.e
$.plot($('#graph_with_zoom'), [data], plot_options).zoom({
'amount': total_ticks / 5,
'center': { left: 0, top: 0 }
});
```

has anyone had the same issue? If so, does anyone have a solution to it please?

Comment: If you have over 1000 ticks you are zooming by a factor of over 200. Are you sure you don't zoom between two ticks so there are no visible ticks in the zoomed view? And a code snippet or fiddle would be needed to take a further look into this.

Comment: Here is a quick fiddle I just whipped up.
http://jsfiddle.net/s148s35u/2/
As you can see, the x axis were somehow gone

Comment: Just playing with the fiddle, it seems the main issue are down to fact that we have set left a bit too much; on a 400px chart, if we set it from 400 to 334, it displays correctly. But this raise another questions, how could we calculate the exact value for the left property?  (first assumption was if the chart is **x** px, then set it as x, but this is apparently not the way to go, does any one have a better idea how it can be achieves? e.g show the last 5 or 10 points?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right in your comment, the `left` property is given in pixels, but the chart itself in your example is not 400 pixels wide. It is only about 336 pixels wide, the rest is y axis and free space to the left and right.

You get the width of the chart itself with `pl.width()`, but unfortunatly this only gives you an integer (336 in your example) while the optimum value for the `left` property seems to be ~336.333.

After some try and error I found this formula which seems to work for different canvas width and different point counts:

```
pl.zoom({
    'amount': nZoom,
    'center': { left: pl.width() * (1 + 1 / total_ticks), top: 0 }
});
```

See this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s148s35u/5/).